# ASPWebApi Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

I have a problem when my angular app try to access to ASP WebApi App, Every one is in a diferent server.
When my angular app try to access, I receive the message: "from origin 'http://ubex:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

I've try to enable CORS in diferent ways (Global, Contoller an Action) according with the documents that I've found, but the problem persists.

When I run my angular app, I run: $ ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200  --disable-host-check
If I run without "disable-host-check" the app does not run.

This is my WebApi.config.cs:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Enable CORS: le estamos permitiendo a la direccion:4200 consumir la aplicacion con todo y sus metodos
        // config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("http://ubex:4200", headers:"*", methods:"*"));
        // config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("http://192.168.100.152:4200", headers: "*", methods: "*"));


        EnableCorsAttribute cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://192.168.100.152:4200", "*", "GET,POST");
        config.EnableCors(cors);


        // Web API configuration and services

        //Configuración para verificar la seguridad del CORS
        //var corsAttr = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
        //config.EnableCors(corsAttr);
```

As you can see, I've tried in severan ways, this is the headers added to my web.config:

```
<httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>

          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
          <!--<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, Origin, X-Requested-With, Accept" />-->
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
        <!--
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST,GET,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE" />
        -->
      </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

I've add this module (just in case) :

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"></modules>
```

This is my angular service:

```
export class EmployeeService { 

 formData: Employee; 
 readonly rootURL = "http://192.168.100.151:44344/api"
 constructor( private _http: HttpClient ) { }

 postEmployee ( formData: Employee ) {
   return this._http.post( this.rootURL + '/Employee', formData );
 }
}
```

Please, I need to know, Do I'm missing something, I hope anyone can help me..

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you are having this issue mostly only in your development environment, where the API is hosted in IIS, and you run the Angular app using `npm run` or `ng serve` which spins of a Node based lite server.

To tackle this, you do not need to add CORS headers, meaning there is an easier way to deal with this: **Angular's proxy config** (actually it is webpack's). Setup a `proxy-config.json` that acts as a proxy for your API requests. Typically, it would contain a JSON as below:

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:3000",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

There are many blogs on this topic apart from [Angular docs - Proxy to backend](https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server). Here are a few:

- Fix CORS in Angular 8: Using CLI proxy configuration by Alex Ssanya https://link.medium.com/taMNLwiIr2
- Angular — How To Proxy To Backend Server by Bhargav Bachina https://link.medium.com/LUJlg1zIr2 (very detailed, but BEWARE, this may require a Medium subscription.)

Here is another if you are facing this issue in production actually. “Angular 2+ does not support a proxy in prod build and how to resolve it with API.NET RESTful API” by Thanh Nguyen Tien https://link.medium.com/nONOmotIr2

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Krishnan.

I created the configuration proxy file:

```
{
"/api/*": {
"target": "http://192.168.100.151:80"
, "secure": false
, "changeOrigin": true
, "logLevel": "debug"
, "pathRewrite": {
  "^/api": "http://192.168.100.151:80/api"
}
```

}
}

Reference the proxy configuration in angular.json:

```
"serve": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
      "options": {
        "browserTarget": "app10crudapi:build"
        , "proxyConfig": "proxy.conf.json"
      },
```

(just in case)I allowed incomming connections in WebApi server:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://192.168.100.151:80/ user=everyone
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="IISWeb123" dir=in protocol=tcp localport=80 
profile=private remoteip=localsubnet action=allow
```

this is for the local subnet

I checked the Access-Control-Allow-Origin in the IIS configuration, because it has multiple values (I don't know why), but Its working now.

On my WebApiConfig.cs:

```
 public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        EnableCorsAttribute cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://192.168.100.152:4200", "*", "GET,POST");
        config.EnableCors(cors);
```